# Simulate frameset using iframes

Tags: javascript, ipad, layout, iframe, frames

I am writing an application using HTML/Javascript/CSS.  It's not, but for sake of this question, let's say it's a photo browser application with treeview of folders in a left pane and zoomable photo preview in right pane.

```
 +---------+---------------------+
 |        ^|                     |
 |        #|                     |
 | tree   ||       zoomable      |
 | view   ||       image         |
 | with   ||       preview       |
 | scroll ||                     |
 | bar    |+---------------------+
 |        ||                     |
 |        v|       details       |
 +---------+---------------------+
```

At the moment I'm using a frameset and this works great on the likes of Chromium, IE9.

However, I'd like to support the iPad whose frameset support is somewhat peculiar and perhaps even non-standard.

I considered YUI Layout Manager and similar.  However, resize is not "live" with these and does not happen until the spacer bar is released.  With a frameset in most browsers, the frames' content resizes while dragging.  This makes app feel more like an app and is an important part of the UX

Now it strikes me that it should be possible to replicate a frameset by using iframes, spacer divs and some javascript to resize.  This is probably quite straightforward so to my question:  has this been done before?  If not, is there a library that would make it easy?

Comment: Have you considered not using frames at all? The common consensus these days seem to be that frames are evil and should be avoided like the plague. Is there a reason you can't have everything on the page using divs and overflow:scroll;?

Comment: I guess that would work but it would mean loading the divs using AJAX as they interact with each other.  Also - is it possible to have "live" resizing of divs' content as the spacer bar is dragged?

Comment: With the right JavaScript it's possible to do pretty much anything. [Example](http://www.twinhelix.com/javascript/dragresize/demo/)